# What Normal Form does this violate?

Tags: database-design, normalization, database-normalization

A colleague has proposed this database table:

```
table vatdata (
    storeCode integer,
    returnDate date,
    itemID integer,
    numValue money,
    UNIQUE (storeCode,returnDate,itemID) )
```

...where itemID is one of fifty or so numeric codes that indicate the value stored.

Now, whether or this is a good idea is not (for reasons of professionalism and politeness) is something I'm not interested in discussing here.  What I do want to ask is, **which particular normal form does this break?**

I'm sure it must break a normal form, but I can't for the life of me work out which one. And I'm equally sure I've seen this discussed a dozen times, but I'm completely failing to turn up any discussion of it in a search.

---

EDIT: Functional Dependencies:

Each store, each day, must enter a dozen or so values.  Each value is stored in `numValue` and the nature of the value is identified by `itemID` (which is a foreign key).

So it seems that `numValue` is functionally dependent on the other three fields -- unless I am missing some technicality of the term "functional dependency"

Comment: What are the functional dependencies? Why are you sure it must "break a normal form"?

Comment: This may or may not break a normal form.  If it does, I'd _guess_ that it is 2nd, since `returnDate` doesn't feel like it depends on `itemID`.  Instead, this _sounds_ like it is an example of Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV), which is widely reviled - and for (mostly) good reasons.  Mike Sherrill makes a good point in his comment.  You should clarify the functional dependencies if you want to understand what normal form your table is in.

Comment: Echoing the earlier comment, you can't answer this question with an explicit statement of the functional dependencies.  You must add this to your question if you expect a real answer.

Comment: Edited to add something about functional dependencies. Mike, I confess: I think it breaks normal form because it seems like bad database design. In my experience anything that looks like bad database structure breaks one of the first four. There is no more logical reason.

Comment: @Joel -- yes, this is an EAV table. I'd not heard of the term before. The "enitity" in this case is (`storeCode` + `returnDate`).

Comment: There is nothing apparently wrong with this table, as you have presented it here.  With more information (such as the other tables and relations in the db) something might become apparent, but right now there's nothing obvious wrong with it.  There may be some question as to whether `ItemID` should part of the key or part of the data, but that's likely a quibble.

Comment: Now I know the term EAV, I'm getting more search results -- [this](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/160700/which-aspect-of-normal-forms-do-entity-attribute-value-tables-violate-if-any) question is relevant, for example.

Comment: One cannot determine what normal form(s) a table is in without knowing all the FDs. You have not given enough information for us to know them all. See my comment on the accepted answer: Even the answerer agrees that hey just assumed {storeCode,returnDate,itemID} is candidate key. So if your design lacks two particular FDs, which is probably so, the table is in 6NF; but if it has either, which is unlikely but possible, it isn't. Unless you can show that that set is candidate key, there's no reason to think that the design satisfies 6NF; there is only reason to think it's probably in 6NF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a key plus one single attribute, the design satisfies 6NF.

And since there is currently no NF above 6, no normal form at all is violated.

Don't misrepresent this as also implying that it is a good design (the EAV link has already been pointed out to you).

Comment: Assuming the UNIQUE is a candidate key.

Comment: "Each store, each day, must enter a dozen or so values".  No assuming needed, unless you think that either of {returndate itemid} -> storeCode and {StoreCode itemid} -> returndate might be reasonable.  Farfetched imo.

Comment: The point is you need to know in order to answer the question, & you don't. The farfetchedess is in the realm of what is the right design; it has nothing to to with normalization given a design.

Comment: That's exactly the realm that this site operates in.  Or at least the realm most database questions are in and also the realm from which the OP's expect the most useful answers.  (Meaning yes you are right but here on SO, that's nitpicking taken to the extreme.)

Comment: "Most useful answer" is a misrepresentation. "Answer for the most likely case (with the OP probably not able to competently determine whether it's their case)" is accurate.

Comment: :-)  You're right again.  (commenting just to have the last word here.)

Comment: @philipxy - and you are assuming my competency or lack of it, so assumptions all around. ;)  For the record: I agree with Erwin. There is enough information in the question I posted to infer the candidate keys with 99% certainty. If you are still unsure, I'll happily answer any question more instructional than "Tell us the FDs!" I'm under the impression that I already have.

Comment: @AndyJones I'm just going by what you wrote in your question & comments. Eg your EDIT gives no information at all about FDs yet you think it does. Eg you think you've given the FDs and you haven't. If you think you have, that contradicts only "99% accuracy". (Which as an oxymoron is already self-contradictory). It's also wrong, as Erwin has agreed. What does "more instructional" mean? We are telling you how to determine normal forms. That's how you do it, there's no other way.

Comment: @AndyJones I don't know how my last comment is not being nice. It just states a bunch of technical facts. Re that and my mentioning (which it justified) your understanding, I already had a draft addressing those issues before I posted any comments but it awaits time. PS Please, what does your "instructional" sentence mean?

Comment: @AndyJones If {returnDate,itemId} and {storeCode,itemId} are both not UNIQUE then just say so in your question because then the current UNIQUE triplet is a CK and Erwin's answer applies. (I thought you understood this from our comments.) (And you could look up the definition of FD.) (And CK.)

Comment: Erwin: For the triplet to be a CK the two possible subsets that need to not be UNIQUE that we don't already know about are {returndate,itemId} and {storeCode,itemid}. Either UNIQUE requires an FD to both other attributes. (Not 1 which we were saying.) (Even more unlikely of course.)

Comment: @philipxy - re uniqueness: look at the question again. If the table was unique on a subset of the things I said the table was unique on, I would have said that the table was unique on something different. :/

Comment: @philipxy - re "instructional": clearly you have far more technical knowledge on this subject than I do. This should be apparent to both of us, since I am the one asking the question.  You were the fourth person to ask me to "show you the FD's" even after I had made the a comment saying I had edited the Q to try to show them.  If you wanted more information you needed to _instruct_ me more clearly on what information you wanted.  This Q is closed, and this will be my last response here. I note that I can flag comments as "unhelpful"...